# Is possible to change the decision variable type for cplex in python?

Tags: cplex, docplex

(1) When I define decision variables for cplex in python,

```
x = np.empty((6,1), dtype= object)
for i in range(6):
    x[i] = mdl.integer_var(lb= 0, ub= inf, name='x' + str(i+1))
```

How can I change the type of decision variables for x from integer_var to integer_var_list?

(2) When I define the decision variables as follows.

```
x = mdl.integer_var_list(6, 0, inf, name='x')
```

The size of x is (6, ). How can I define x as integer_var_list for size of (6,1) ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use integer_var_matrix

Example in

[Sorting the decision variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73047996/sorting-the-decision-variables/73050748#73050748)

```
permx = mdl.integer_var_matrix(r,r,name="xperm")
```